# How can I output execution display to console in Eclipse for remote C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, remote-debugging, eclipse-3.4

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.1 with Hp/UX plugin for remote debugging of C/C++. It works very fine, except for one issue: whenever I compile my projects, the output display is Eclipse's console view, but when I run or debug any projects, the output window is the old and not-so-good MS-DOS command window. I haven't find any way to change this behavior.

How do I set the execution output display to Eclipse console?

**Update**: 
Environment: running Eclipse 3.4.1 on Windows XP and debugging C/C++ applications on an HP/UX server.

CDT version is 5.0.0.

Comment: You might like to add info about your environment. I was sure you sat on Linux until you mentioned MS-DOS windows..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of CDT are you using? Because from this ["hello world" guide](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s04.jsp#N10321) it seems the spawner.dll pretty much handles this console redirection for you.

Comment: Thought my CDT version is pretty recent, the strange solution of deleting the spawner.dll file solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: That is unusual, but I do find it to be case that certain open-sourced projects ignore problems in their non-core users. Not intentionally, but because they don't setup any thorough tests for these cases. So it doesn't surprise me that a bug from 3+ years ago would come back in the latest version.